# GPG encrypt and decrypt with ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, gpg

I use **`ssh`** regularly and have **`ssh-agent`** set up.

How can I use **`ssh`** keys to **`gpg`**-encrypt a file?

**Edit**: It seems that this is impossible. Why? **`ssh`** can encrypt traffic, so why not also files?

Comment: See also gpg-agent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SSH keys are not PGP keys and serve different purpose .
You must have PGP keys in GnuPG keyring.
But - you can convert GPG keys to SSH keys (using `gpgkey2ssh`) and gpg-agent can take care of SSH keys (using --enable-ssh option). I believe no such tool exists for converting SSH keys to GPG keys and cannot exist.

Comment: I prefer to work in the reverse: use gpg with ssh keys, since I already have an extensive ssh infrastructure.

Comment: that is not possible. Just view size of SSH public key and GPG public key -> SSH key contains much less info.

Comment: Okay, some things are not possible with SSH keys but I believe that encryption **is possible** since ssh encrypts traffic. Perhaps I should have asked: How can I encrypt a file with an SSH key?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/encrypting-file-only-with-ssh-priv-key answers that question.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that this is impossible. Why? ssh can encrypt traffic, so why not also files?

SSH can encrypt, just not in a GPG compatible manner.

Per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/encrypting-file-only-with-ssh-priv-key:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in my.pdf -out mydata.enc
```

and

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in mydata.enc -out mydecrypted.pdf
```

should do the trick.